# OpenCL: Better to use more registers, or to pack values using bit-shift operators?

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL, on GPUs, register pressure will reduce occupation rates, so we want to reduce the number of registers used.

In my program, I have tons of values, that are not known at compile time, but are typically in the range 0 to 127.  I'm wondering whether it might be better to pack these into a smaller number of registers, using bit-shift operators, rather than use tons of registers for these?

eg, maybe create some macros like:

```
#define posToRow( pos ) ( ( pos >> 10 ) & ((1<<10)-1) )
#define posToCol( pos ) ( ( pos ) & ((1<<10)-1) )
#define rowColToPos( row, col ) ( ( row << 10 ) | col )
#define linearIdToPos( linearId, base ) ( rowColToPos( ( linearId / base ), ( linearId % base )  ) )
```

Thoughts on this?  Any experiences with this?  It would seem that the advantages/disadvantages are:

- using bitshift involves slightly more computation (but: bitshifts are fast?)
- ... but fewer registers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will probably not answer your question the way you want it.

> In OpenCL, on GPUs, register pressure will reduce occupation rates, so we want to reduce the number of registers used.

Register pressure will indeed reduce occupancy, but that does not imply it will reduce performance as a consequence: it depends on many other factors. If you haven't read it yet, I strongly encourage you to read Vasily Volkov's [Better Performance at Lower Occupancy](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf).

> I'm wondering whether it might be better to pack these into a smaller number of registers, using bit-shift operators, rather than use tons of registers for these?

A very important rule in a developer's life is "don't optimize yet". This rule still stands even in high-performance code:

- **First**, get your code to work correctly.
- **Then**, if you find that performance is unsatisfactory and/or could be improved, *profile* it.
- And **then**, identify the bottleneck and try to find a solution.

All in all, it is pointless to try to guess *in advance* about what may or may not create register pressure. Implement, measure, act. Don't try to forecast issues that do not exist yet and may very well never exist at all.

That being said, most of the time (if not always), when writing high-performance code (even "standard" code, actually), the only way to know which option is the fastest between several is to implement all of them and benchmark them. As such, I am afraid your question will have no definitive answer until you do such a benchmark.

Comment: That's a great paper /presentation you just linked to.  Very interesting :-)  As far as should I be optimizing, I already have a bunch of plausibly-performant kernels, https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/tree/master/cl , and what I'm trying to do now is optimize them.  As far as benchmarking, benchmarking only goes so far, since I only have access to one type of nvidia gpu, and one type of intel gpu, no amd or other gpus, so I need some ideas of what will work generally, without being able to actually try on every device :-P

Comment: It's already difficult enough to optimize for *one* target hardware. Optimizing while remaining portable (performance-wise) is extremely difficult.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Perhaps I just stick to optimizing for nvidia for now.  If AMD want AMD-optimizations they can provide access to amd gpu cloud or something :-)  Mind you, this begs the question, why don't I just use caffe, on cuda, and have done with it :-P

Comment: Note that you've totally avoided answering my question, but the link to Vokov's paper is super useful, and there are no other answers yet, so marking your answer as accepted for now :-)

Answer (score 1):

As most of the answers above already mentioned, be aware not to overoptimize your code.
Are your values typically between 0 and 127 or are these values ALWAYS within this range. Otherwise (you did not mention, if you had already tried): why don't you turn to vector data (`unsigned char16`)?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, unfortunately whenever you do arithmetic on anything smaller than `int`, it will get promoted to `int`, and therefore use as many registers than a raw `int`. It will use less memory, however.

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara If it's being stored in registers as ints, one value per 32-bit int register, why would it use less memory?

Comment: Memory is not registers. If you declare your variable as `char`, it'll use 1/4th of the space of an `int`.

Comment: You're right. I wanted to point out, that "typically in the range of" could mean "one of hundred is outside the range", so this makes the compression needless.